# Ionic Framework different image for device

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i am developing an ios and android app from Ionic. my problem is since we have different device, different density. How do you handle the displaying of images. Are you just creating one image file that will be used on all the screen device?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that yes you use one high quality image and let the browser on the device do the down scaling.

The slightly longer answer is that you can do some optimizations because your locked into a pretty tight set of standards compliant browsers so you'll want to follow best practices for those. By that I mean if you have graphics that are in vector format, great leave them as SVG's if you can. If you have raster images you'll want to have them at a resolution that looks great on your biggest retina display and you'll want to use media queries to adjust where necessary.

You can also use CSS tricks to replace images by hiding and showing appropriate images at appropriate times.

Comment: I think the short answer will do :)  But what tricks did you use, the longer answer or the short answer that you post?

Comment: So I've done multiple img tags that I set initially to display:none then show with media queries. I've also successfully done background images for different media queries in ionic apps. With both of these options with most phone browsers the images aren't loaded until that CSS can be hit.